# Работа с изображениями в D

Tags: массивы, изображения, матрицы, bmp, d

У меня есть двумерный массив булевых значений (bool[][]), и мне нужно записать этот массив в BMP. То есть, к примеру, есть такая матрица:

```
[0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 1]
```

и мне нужно каким-то образом получить из нее .bmp файл с изображением цифры "1". То бишь, true — черный пиксель, false — белый. Как можно это сделать в D?

Comment: формат bmp достаточно прост. Если генерировать картинку нужной битности, то заголовок можно и захардкодить. А потом просто скопировать туда массив с битами. Главное помнить, что в bmp картинки хранятся вверх тормашками.

Comment: А еще ширина строки должна быть выровнена до кратности 4 пикселям

Comment: Чем обусловлен выбор bmp?

Comment: @Dmi7ry, насколько я знаю, BMP как формат довольно прост и при этом популярен, а значит, наверняка существуют библиотеки для него на многих языках, в том числе и на D.

Comment: Уже "сто лет" стандартом де-факто для растровой графики без потери качества является png, смысла использовать bmp нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для записи BMP можете воспользоваться, например, библиотекой [arsd](https://github.com/adamdruppe/arsd), из которой потребуется модули `bmp` и `color`.

```
import arsd.bmp, arsd.color;

void main()
{
    ubyte[][] image = [
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    ];

    auto col = [Color.black, Color.green];

    auto w = image[0][].length;
    auto h = image[].length;

    ubyte[] data;

    for (int j=0; j<h; j++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<w; i++)
        {
            auto val = image[j][i];
            data ~= col[val].r;
            data ~= col[val].g;
            data ~= col[val].b;
            data ~= col[val].a;
        }
    }

    auto img = new TrueColorImage(w, h, data);
    writeBmp(img, "result.bmp");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
import imageformats.png;
uint[][] im;
foreach(i; 0..10) im ~= new uint[10];
im[4][5] = 0xff_ff_00_00;

auto m = read_png("n.png").to_int;
m[10][10] = 0xff_00_ff_00;
write_png("1.png", m[0].length, m.length, m.to_byte);
*/


auto to_byte(uint[][] m){
    ubyte[] data;

    union BI {
        struct{ ubyte b1, b2, b3, b4; }
        uint n;
    }

    int w = m.length;
    int h = m[0].length;

    foreach(y; 0..h){
        foreach(x; 0..w){
            BI bi;
            bi.n = m[x][y];
            data ~= bi.b1;
            data ~= bi.b2;
            data ~= bi.b3;
            data ~= bi.b4;
        }
    }

    return data;
}


auto to_int(T)(T data){
    uint[][] im;
    foreach(i; 0..data.w) im ~= new uint[data.h];

    union BI {
        struct{ ubyte b1, b2, b3, b4; }
        uint n;
    }

    int n = 0;
    foreach(y; 0..data.h){
        foreach(x; 0..data.w){
            BI bi;
            bi.b1 = data.pixels[n++];
            bi.b2 = data.pixels[n++];
            bi.b3 = data.pixels[n++];
            if(data.c == 3) bi.b4 = 0xff;
            if(data.c == 4) bi.b4 = data.pixels[n++];
            im[x][y] = bi.n;
        }
    }

    return im;
}
```